Electron cannot find tmp node files on some installs
We have an electron application that is built using vite and the electron-builder using the --windows flag.
Since the last release we have gotten complaints from users that cannot start the app anymore. Because they all get the following error:
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\{some.user}\AppData\Local\Temp\{some.guid}.tmp.node
  at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1869)
  at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:18)
  at Object.fund [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2096)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1011:32)
  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
  at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\{install.path}\resources\app.asar\)

The only problem is that it happens for only a very small set of users and so far I have not been able to reproduce it on my own machine.
I have tried, to reinstall it on the user's end and have also rebuilt the app's installer. But it seems to do nothing. Given that I cannot reproduce it, it makes it difficult to determine what to try.
I have also read that I should put "asar": true. But this was already the case before this problem came about.
